# angular js: filter unwanted item in the list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

The code is in angular js. I able to get a list from a link in json but I need to filter unwanted items in the list.

If the id is more than 4 digits, then remove full_name,name, short_name and id. example: if id:123456 , it need to be filter out.

**app.js**

```
  kls: {
      name: "Momo",
      value: "kls",
      long: "KLSE",
      searchRef: KLSE_SEARCH_REF,
      searchRefURL: "http://www.bursamalaysia.com/searchbox_data.json",

    },
```

**details.js**

```
  $ionicLoading.show();
  if($scope.currentMarket == "kls") {
    $webServicesFactory.getNotParsed($marketProvider[$scope.currentMarket].searchRefURL).then(
      function success(response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        for(var i=0; i<response[0].length; i+=1){
          $scope.searchRef.push(
            {
              name: response[0][i].name || response[0][i].full_name,
              symbol: response[0][i].short_name,
              code: response[0][i].id,
              market: $marketProvider[$scope.currentMarket].long
            }
          );
        }
        console.info($scope.searchRef);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
      }
    );
  }
```

**html**

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in searchItems" ng-click="openDetail(item)">
    <p>{{item.symbol}} - {{item.name}}</p>
    <p>{{currentMarket | uppercase}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do IDs come into this?

Comment: @Phil edited.missed out one line

Answer (score 0):

Try to build an custom filter function, like:

```
function filterData(data) {
    return data.filter(function (val) {
        return String(val.id).length <= 4;
    });
}
```

Bind it to your scope/controller and change your repeat to:

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in filterData(searchItems)" ng-click="openDetail(item)">
```